# conda create error: Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

Tags: python, anaconda

An annoying error occurs when creating a virtual environment using 'conda create':
**Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR for url https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/repos/cross-platform/win-64/current_repodata.json**

My machine info: win 11(64 bit), Anaconda 2020.07 for Windows.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3csk.png)

I tried the following methods to resolve the issue:

1. I tried typing 'conda config --set ssl_verify False' in cmd.
2. 

Open the path "AnacondaPath/Library/bin/"
Copy the following four files

- libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
- libcrypto-1_1-x64.pdb
- libssl-1_1-x64.dll
- libssl-1_1-x64.pdb
  Paste into the path "AnacondaPath/DLLs/"

3. conda update jupyter
   conda update nbconvert
4. Reinstalling Anaconda

But none of those methods solved the problem.
I haven't been able to resolve it for days. Please help me...

Comment: Please post the error as text, and not a screenshot.